# What's the difference between PowerPivot and regular pivot tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I keep reading how PowerPivot lets Excel process "millions of rows" (!!). I'm already doing this with a regular old pivot table hooked up to a (relational) SQL database. What does PowerPivot do differently?

Comment: PowerPivots are like by marketing more, so they got a better name.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com/) features:

> 1. Take advantage of familiar Excel tools and features
> 2. Process massive amounts of data in seconds
> 3. Load even the largest data sets from virtually any source
> 4. Use powerful new analytical capabilities, such as Data Analysis Expressions (DAX)
> 5. Make the most of multi-core processors and gigabytes of memory

You can read the [datasheet](http://www.powerpivot.com/res/pdf/PowerPivotdatasheetIW.pdf) for more info.

In short, it seems that it was built more efficiently, to handle larger data loads, automatically parallelizes across cores, and has more analysis tools.

Comment: Ouch, fixing that now. Thanks for telling me.